# Date format in imported variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a date field as the index. The following will serve as an example

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
index = date_range('2/1/2015', periods=8))
df = DataFrame(rand.randn(8, 1), index=index, columns=['A'])
print df
                   A
2015-02-01  1.624345
2015-02-02 -0.611756
2015-02-03 -0.528172
2015-02-04 -1.072969
2015-02-05  0.865408
2015-02-06 -2.301539
2015-02-07  1.744812
2015-02-08 -0.761207
```

I am defining a 'start' and 'end' variable like this:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2015,2,2)
end = datetime.datetime(2015,2,6)
```

...and accessing the index like this:

```
xStart = df.index.get_loc(start)
print xStart
xEnd = df.index.get_loc(end)
print xEnd
1
5
```

I would like to have the values for the variables 'start' and 'end' stored in a csv file, where they can be updated once and accessed by multiple scripts. But the format is causing me a problem

I have imported a csv file like this:

```
datefile = r'c:\testt\datefile.csv'
df2 = pd.read_csv(datefile, names=['date'])

print df2

         date
0  2015,02,6
```

...and tried various date formats, both in the csv file and after it has been imported to the DataFrame, but I get a TypeError message every time.

Can anybody suggest how I might make this work?

EDIT -- add traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-f2f0b55d49f7> in <module>()
----> 1 xEnd = df.index.get_loc(end)
      2 print xEnd

C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in get_loc(self, key)
   1307 
   1308         try:
-> 1309             return Index.get_loc(self, key)
   1310         except (KeyError, ValueError):
   1311             try:

C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.pyc in get_loc(self, key)
   1154         loc : int if unique index, possibly slice or mask if not
   1155         """
-> 1156         return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
   1157 
   1158     def get_value(self, series, key):

C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:9475)()

C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\index.pyd in pandas.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:8954)()

TypeError:
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you get as error text? Please past the whole traceback.

Comment: This line is odd `df2 = pd.read_csv(datefile, names=['date'])`, if you're wanting your date column to be parsed as a datetime then you need to indicate this; `df2 = pd.read_csv(datefile, names=['date'], parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'])`

Comment: @EdChum. Thanks. I was trying to make the imported content match the format of the variables which worked when entered manually. I don't know specifically what format is needed -- it would be whatever will allow the index.get_loc line to work. I still get the same TypeError message using the line you suggest.

Comment: if you're using integers to slice your df why not just use `df.iloc[start:end]`? passing the integer row indices?

Comment: it's a small section of a much larger script. I need the rest to remain intact if at all possible. Just trying to replace a manually entered variable which works with an equivalent passed in from a csv file. The line 'end = datetime.datetime(2015,2,6)' works as intended, just trying to pass it a date from an external file instead.

Comment: @EdChum. A fuller answer would be that it's not a slice per se, there are various calculations forward of this point that reference specific rows. I thought that passing the date criteria in a different manner would be simple, but can't find the right way.